# Appium Submit Url

Tags: webdriver, appium, appium-android, remotewebdriver, python-appium

I am using Python and Android Chrome. And my `WebDriver` is created using `WebDriver.Remote(host, caps)`

I actually want to use Chrome in incognito mode but it seems not possible according to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568714/open-chrome-in-incognito-mode-on-real-android-device-using-appium).

But are there any workaround? For example, can I submit my url to the url bar of Chrome at the top? I have tried `driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.chrome:id/url_bar').submit()` but it says not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround. Explanations are in the comments.

```
# Open Menu/More Button
d.find_element_by_id('com.android.chrome:id/menu_button').click()

# Click On Incognito Mode
d.find_element_by_xpath('/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]').click()

# Find Url Bar on the top
url_bar = d.find_element_by_id('com.android.chrome:id/url_bar')

# Click on it which gives you another view.
url_bar.click()

# Set url and this gives you a list of options
url_bar.set_text('https://a.lianwifi.com/app_h5/jisu/wifiapk/sms.html?c=uvtest&type=1')

# Click the first one. This is the one that leads you to the page with your url.
d.find_element_by_xpath('/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.ListView/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix 2 incompatible approaches to mobile automation using Appium.

1. If you want to use [Selenium API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) normally in order to control mobile browser like a desktop browser:

   - Instantiate your AppiumDriver like:

     ```
     desired_caps = {}
     desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
     desired_caps['browserName'] = 'chrome'
     driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
     ```

     then to open the URL just use [driver.get()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) function like:

     ```
     driver.get('http://example.com')
     ```
2. If you want to use [Appium API](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/api/) and treat Chrome as any other mobile application you need to provide a little bit different set of [desired capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) and specify Chrome [package and activity](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/)

   ```
   desired_caps = {}
   desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
   desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.chrome'
   desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main'
   driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
   ```

Check out [Appium - > Code Examples -> Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Python) article for more information on automating mobile browsers/applications including code snippets

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sorry you didn't get my question. I have found my workaround and posted.